# multiple server set up for web based application

Tags: mysql

First off please excuse me if this is short and sweet as I'm typing this from a phone currently..

Overall I am trying to find out specifics on setting up multiple dedicated machines for hosting a web based application. Currently we do not have a direct requirement for this need, but the need is expected shortly and i want to make sure in the initial setup of everything that future expandablity is a semi smooth transaction rather then a huge mess.

My main concern is the database. We are using mysql and I have only seen it in use in a single machine environment as a full lamp stack. But i am wondering how I would work it to go across multiple machines as it grows. Not only on a storage level physicaly but on accessiblity to the app. My first thought is 2+ machines where the databases mirror only in structure but not data, however issues I foresee with that is data availability as data on machine 1 may be needed from the app where as data from machines 2+ will be required as well, but the data being dynamic in nature would require me to query every db til needed matches are found which seems overkill on the processing. So with that is it possible for the machines to spill over into the next making one massive dataset between them?

Overall like I said it deals with storage constraints and also bottle necking issues as i would like to manage them in a way were I can balance the loads.

I don't really know where else to look for information, my searches yield nothing relevant and that's likely due to just not looking for the right stuff so any advise here would be greatly appreciated as a starting / end point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a HAProxy Gateway that will accept all of the traffic. This will allow you to host multiple physical or virtual servers. Basically each request will go through the HAProxy Gateway machine and be sent to one of the X number of servers in your High Availability cluster. Each one of your servers will have the WWW data and you can have a separate database server. The MySQL database server can be replicated or configured in a cluster with managed servers.